# How are "memoirs" counted as a "set"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Send at once $3.00 for year's subscription to The Cosmopolitan, $1.00 for year's subscription to The Literary Northwest and 50 cents for *a set of memoirs* - $4.50 in all - to which add postage on the particular set of memoirs selected.

[Source](https://encrypted.google.com/books?id=3IE4AQAAMAAJ&pg=PR6&dq=%22a%20set%20of%20memoirs%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Y46eU8LWN4XaoASgmoIo&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBw).

The noun, "memoir", is counted as a "set"?

We usually say, "She published a new memoir."

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to describe a book of this genre:

**Memoirs** is used as a fixed plural form, to indicate that it involves not just a single memory, but several ones.

> She published her memoirs last year.

**Memoir** is also used to describe the same, but it is descriptive of the whole book, the collection of memories.

> She published her memoir.

Interestingly, the two forms to describe "person's written account of his life" are almost contemporary to each other according to [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=memoir&searchmode=none). For *memoirs*, there is a bit wider definition of "personal record of events", where the events do not have to span a person's lifetime.

Now, your source is a book from 1892, and it seems that here we have a third form. A memoir would be seen as just a single memory, and in a book you would have several of those. To indicate that plural, instead of using the (as far as I know, now common) *memoirs*, the authors chose to refer to them as a *set of memoirs*.
You can read *set of memoirs* as "a collection of personal records of events".

Compare also to what happened to *a pair of jeans*, it is common to read *she wears jeans*.

Comment: Wondering if the downvoter would care to share their concerns?

Answer (score 0):

The use of *set* is occasioned by the plurality of the term *Memoirs* for works of this sort.

If you look at the main part of this advertisement you will see that what is being offered is

> The two splendid volumes of Grant's Memoirs [...]
>     If however you have Grant's books this offer will permit you to take instead

... and there follows a list of four alternatives: Sherman's Memoirs (2 vols.), Sheridan's (2 vols.), McClellan's (1 vol.) or Lee's (1 vol.)

And after the passage you have quoted the publisher tells you to

> add postage on the particular set of memoirs selected.

The publisher is understandably reluctant to specify this indefinite offering as  *one Memoirs* or *a Memoirs* —that's very awkward English. He's equally reluctant to speak of bare *Memoirs*, lest he be understood as offering multiple works. And he cannot offer you *one book*, because some of the offers comprise **two** books.

He therefore settles on designating each of the alternatives a ***set*** of memoirs, of which some have two volumes, others only one.

Answer (score 0):

> **Memoir** (noun)
>
> 2. an essay on a learned subject: "an important memoir on Carboniferous crustacea"

They could be using *memoirs* as a synonym for *essays,* with *set* being used for *collection*.

Also, and this is conjecture, they could be using *set* in conjunction with *memoirs* to mean *the individual memoirs of multiple authors*.